# How to simulate ad hoc network nodes?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I have classes Source, Intermediate and Destination. Source class has method which with some probability receives new packets to send. Whenever packet is received it should be broadcasted (simulated by some setPacket method) to all neighbor intermediate nodes. Intermediate nodes should broadcast those packets to their neighbors until packets reach destination. The problem is whenever the chain of packet transmission is started source node stops running its method for getting new packets. So, basically the source class is frozen while chain of functions are working. Is there any way to run these two processes simultaneously? (It's like Source node will send request to Intermediate class and that one will do it's work independently) I tried for each of three classes to extend Thread class but still transmission chain is freezing Source class. The language used is Java, but if there any other language that could do the job, I can switch to them.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // init nodes
        SourceNode sourceNode = new SourceNode();
        IntermediateNode intermediateNode1 = new IntermediateNode();
        IntermediateNode intermediateNode2 = new IntermediateNode();
        IntermediateNode intermediateNode3 = new IntermediateNode();
        DestinationNode destinationNode = new DestinationNode();

        // create network topology, S - I - I - I - D
        sourceNode.setNextNode(intermediateNode1);
        intermediateNode1.setNextNode(intermediateNode2);
        intermediateNode2.setNextNode(intermediateNode3);
        intermediateNode3.setNextNode(destinationNode);

        // setup listeners
        sourceNode.setSetupMessageListener(intermediateNode1);
        intermediateNode1.setSetupMessageListener(intermediateNode2);
        intermediateNode2.setSetupMessageListener(intermediateNode3);
        intermediateNode3.setSetupMessageListener(destinationNode);

        sourceNode.run();
    }
}

public interface SetupMessageListener {
    void onNewSetupMessage();
}

public class Node {
    protected SetupMessageListener setupMessageListener;
    protected Node nextNode;
    public void setNextNode(Node nextNode) {
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }
    public void setSetupMessageListener(SetupMessageListener setupMessageListener) {
        this.setupMessageListener = setupMessageListener;
    }
}

import java.util.Random;

public class SourceNode extends Node implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            // simulate generating new setup message with probability 1/10
            Random random = new Random();
            int rv = random.nextInt(10);
            if (rv == 0) {
                createNewSetupMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    public void createNewSetupMessage() {
        System.out.println("New setup message was created in Source Node");
        if (setupMessageListener != null) {
            setupMessageListener.onNewSetupMessage();
        }
    }
}

public class IntermediateNode extends Node implements SetupMessageListener {
    public static int count = 0;
    private int id;
    public IntermediateNode() {
        id = count++;
    }
    @Override
    public void onNewSetupMessage() {
        System.out.println("Intermediate Node " + id + " got notified about setup message");
        // pass setup message to next neighbor
        setupMessageListener.onNewSetupMessage();
    }
}

public class DestinationNode extends Node implements SetupMessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onNewSetupMessage() {
        System.out.println("Destination Node got notified about new setup message");
    }
}
```

And the example output is

```
New setup message was created in Source Node
Intermediate Node 0 got notified about setup message
Intermediate Node 1 got notified about setup message
Intermediate Node 2 got notified about setup message
Destination Node got notified about new setup message
New setup message was created in Source Node
Intermediate Node 0 got notified about setup message
```

However, I want it to be smth like

```
New setup message was created in Source Node
Intermediate Node 0 got notified about setup message
New setup message was created in Source Node
Intermediate Node 1 got notified about setup message
Intermediate Node 0 got notified about setup message
Intermediate Node 2 got notified about setup message
Destination Node got notified about new setup message
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to determine what's wrong.

Comment: Added code and example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the whole message passing is done in the main thread....you need to implement the functionality of `createNewSetupMessage` and `onNewMessageSetup`  as instances of `Runnable` and initiate new threads to run them.

```
public class SetupMessageSender implements Runnable{


    private SetupMessageListener setupMessageListener;

    public SetupMessageSender(SetupMessageListener setupMessageListener){
        this.setupMessageListener = setupMessageListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (setupMessageListener != null) {
            setupMessageListener.onNewSetupMessage();
        }
    }

    public SetupMessageListener getSetupMessageListener() {
        return this.setupMessageListener;
    }

    public void setSetupMessageListener(SetupMessageListener setupMessageListener) {
        this.setupMessageListener = setupMessageListener;
    }
}
```

then

```
    public void createNewSetupMessage() {
                System.out.println("New setup message was created in Source Node");
                Thread smService = new Thread(new SetupMessageSender(this.setupMessageListener));
                smService.start();
            }
```

Be careful though at node listeners `onNewMessageSetup`, because it will need a bit of [syncronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) depending on the topology(e.g if an intermediate node is listener for more than one different nodes), so make it

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onNewSetupMessage() {
        System.out.println("Intermediate Node " + id + " got notified about setup message");
        // pass setup message to next neighbor
        Thread smService = new Thread(new SetupMessageSender(this.setupMessageListener));
        smService.start();
    }
```

Although the 2 methods provide the same functionality and you could implement them at your base class `Node` as a single method.